# Is "Harry didn't look it," correct?

Tags: word-usage

I have never seen **look** is used as a transitive verb. This is from the book Harry Potter. I don't quite get "**Harry didn't look it, but he was very fast.**"

Here is an excerpt for more context.

> Exactly why Dudley wanted a racing bike was a mystery to Harry, as Dudley was very fat and hated exercise -- unless of course it involved punching somebody. Dudley's favorite punching bag was Harry, but he couldn't often catch him.  **Harry didn't look it, but he was very fast.** -- *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*, J.K. Rowling

Comment: It's actually a predicative complement (traditionally called a subject complement) and not an object; *look* is intransitive in your example.  See sense 5 in Macmillan: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/look_1

Comment: You might want to review verbs like: look, appear, seem, sound, commonly referred to as verbs of appearance...These verbs are  not transitive, and they go with adjectives: He seemed ill.;She appeared sleepy. etc. In your example: Harry didn't look fast, but he was fast.

Comment: This is not a transitive use of **look**.  I'd understand it as ellipsis of BE:  *Harry did not look [to be] it, but he was fast*, where **it** refers cataphorically to **fast**.   **To look it** = "to seem (to be) so".

Comment: Compare: "You'd never know he was 72. -- You're right, he certainly doesn't look it. I wonder what he eats."  There, it's anaphora.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo now, the pronoun it replaced the adjective slow in this context. As I know, a pronoun usually replaced a noun word, that's why I thought the verb look here works as a transitive. So, is it common in English that adjective is replaced by pronoun?

Comment: I do not understand why no one else is agreeing with the idea that this is one of the most common forms of speech used by English speakers. All the verbs of appearance are used in this manner as Tᴚoɯɐuo has pointed out for the case here. The state or condition given by the adjective is signaled by it and comes first. To be 72 years old is a state. Ergo, it is an "it", i.e. an age.

Comment: @dan:  **it** there works like **so**. **so** refers to an idea expressed elsewhere in the immediate context, either preceding or following.  *He was very fast but because he had a long stride, he did not seem **so***. That is, he did not seem [very fast].  That is how **it** is functioning.  *He was very fast...but he did not look **it**.*  *He did not seem so, because he had a long stride, but he was very fast*.    He did not look it, but he was very fast.

Comment: @dan: *He did not look it, but I knew he was in great pain.*  There **it** refers to **he was in great pain**.  That is, the reference is to the idea-content, that which is predicated.   In the original example, the content is **he was very fast**.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo is it also correct to say: *Harry didn't look so, but...*?

Comment: **Harry didn't look so, but ....** is not ungrammatical but it's not quite natural either.  We tend to use **so** with **seem**.  *Harry didn't seem so, but he was really quite confused by Hermione's behavior. He told me so later.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo what about *Harry didn't seem it, but...*?

Comment: @dan: Again, not ungrammatical, but not quite natural.  **seem so** and **look it** are the typical collocations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common usage, at least in US/NYC. It can be read as *“Harry didn’t look like he was very fast, but he was very fast.”*

In general, *“So-and-so didn’t look it, but he was [descriptive].”* indicates that So-and-so’s appearance would not lead you to believe that the [descriptive] was accurate, even though the [descriptive] is, in fact, accurate.

Comment: Thanks! I could not find this usage in my dictionary originally. Good to know it!

Comment: The order can be reversed. Joe was very clever, although he didn't look it.

Comment: @dan - Check out the related idiom [_look the part_](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/look+the+part).

Comment: Well, considering that both Harry Potter and J.K. Rowling are British, we can assume it's common in the UK as well.

Comment: @Andrew - Very likely; I just won't make that assertion if I don't have certain knowledge, or documentation to back it up.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin  Sure, but I'd hazard that the book itself is sufficient "documentation"  :)

Comment: Very common in the UK.

Comment: I have to say this: this is exactly the same in BrE and AmE. There simply is no difference here. Andrew doesn't look it, but he's a Californian. And I don't understand why educated speakers (who of us commenting here appear to be) could possibly think otherwise. I assume most of us have heard enough speech from both sides of the pond to realize that. But maybe I'm naive....

Comment: To say it is common in the USA and NY is simply reductionist. It's just English. I would stick my neck out here: almost all forms like these are the same.

Comment: @Lambie I couldn't confidently say that this is common in BrE. To me, "enough speech from both sides of the pond" to confidently say that something is applicable in both is *a lot*. I definitely have not heard enough BrE to think "If this were not common, then I would have noted it not being used before now". Statements that a difference *does* exist are somewhat easier, because that ends up as "something unusual" that sticks out and I remember it, but identifying distinctly that they are the same is much more difficult.

Comment: This is not some unusual English construction. They are tons and tons of ***similar*** ones: She didn't sound it, but she was very happy.\\ I really do not know how to word this otherwise but to say it is very, very usual. Of course, it's not in the dictionary: structures seldom are.